# Using Automator to call a Service

Tags: automator, services, evernote

I use save my PDFs to my Evernote account.  I would like to automate this process at the end of the day.  Can I use Automator to call the existing service "Add to Evernote" at the end of the day?

Comment: PDF's generated from where? You may want to move them to a folder with a folder action attached that runs the Evernote action. A little more information regarding your workflow would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I made such a service.

See

https://blog.tempel.org/2015/09/RunServiceForAutomator.html

and

https://github.com/tempelmann/RunServiceActionForAutomator